# How to prevent val from showing in Html Input (Combobox)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a Html Input (Combobox)

```
<input id="lstMovie" list="movies" name="moviesearch" />
    <datalist id="movies">
</datalist>
```

To fill the data in, I use jQuery as follow:

```
for (var t = 0; t < movies.length; t++) {
    var m = movies[t];
    $("<option/>").val(m.getId()).text(m.getTitle())
    .appendTo("#movies");
}
```

In the end, I have a combobox with those option entries, and on the left of each option there is the id (passed as val()) and on the right side there is the title (passed in text()).

When the user selects an Option the Id is logged in the console.
But I don't want the id (value) to be shown? What can I do to hide the value? I just want the title of each movie to be shown to the user.

[image]

```js
movies = [
  {id: '1', title: 'One'},
  {id: '2', title: 'Two'},
  {id: '3', title: 'Three'},
  {id: '4', title: 'Four'},
]
for (var t = 0; t < movies.length; t++) {
    var m = movies[t];
    $("<option/>").val(m.id).text(m.title)
    .appendTo("#movies");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="lstMovie" list="movies" name="moviesearch" />
    <datalist id="movies">
</datalist>
```

Comment: Please make a working example.

Comment: You want to show the drop-down only with tittle correct ?

Comment: Yes, just show the title of the movie, not it's Id.

Answer (score 1):

Normally I would say, it is part of the Shadow DOM. But in this case I'm not able to find any accessible Shadow DOM for this (at least not in Chrome).

So my answer is: You can't!

Firefox does not show the id at all:
[image: Firefox]

neither does MS Edge:
[image: Edge]

as well as MS IE:
[image]

Comment: Ah, ok, just change the browser. Life can be so simple! :-)

Comment: Firefox 67.0 does show the `id` after selecting an item though

Comment: @user1119859 Why don't you just use a `select` btw?

Comment: @Darkbee I think that's the intended behavior.

Comment: Guess so - I'm not sure why OP would try to use a `datalist` and force the use of `id's` though. Seeing that anything can be entered as input, even items which aren't in the list

Comment: datalists should be used as autocomplete/suggest feature

Answer (score 0):

Change this `$("<option/>").val(m.id).text(m.title)`  To `$("<option/>").val(m.title)`

```js
movies = [{
    id: '1',
    title: 'One'
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    title: 'Two'
  },
  {
    id: '3',
    title: 'Three'
  },
  {
    id: '4',
    title: 'Four'
  },
]
for (var t = 0; t < movies.length; t++) {
  var m = movies[t];
  $("<option/>").val(m.title)
    .appendTo("#movies");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="lstMovie" list="movies" name="moviesearch" />
<datalist id="movies">
</datalist>
```

**You are appending both Id and text just append text only**

Or you can do like this,use `select` Html tag This will be more relevant because it will also have ids but only show `title` inside drop-down

```js
var data = [{
    id: '1',
    title: 'One'
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    title: 'Two'
  },
  {
    id: '3',
    title: 'Three'
  },
  {
    id: '4',
    title: 'Four'
  },
]
let dropdown = $('#myselect');

dropdown.prop('selectedIndex', 0);

$.each(data, function(key, entry) {
  dropdown.append($('<option></option>').attr('value', entry.id).text(entry.title));

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="myselect" class="form-control">

</select>
```

Comment: In this case, you can't have an auto complete on the ids

Comment: User want's an input with datalist, not a select drop down

Comment: @yunzen oh.. correct,  so user can use my first solution, the second one let it be here it can help others

Comment: One can't use your first solution, if you need the id as value, like for database operations.

Comment: @yunzen so in that case i think user needs to change his/her approach towards his requirement

Comment: Maybe, but that doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Ok, so solution would be, just set the text (and not the value), and do a mapping to the data somewhere else. Right ?

Comment: @user1119859 yup you have to do it like that, or you have to look for other approach

Comment: @user1119859 That would not be applicable in the most cases. This of users with names. You might have zillions of John Smiths all with different ids. Ids are for identification, names are not.

Answer (score 0):

Replace from

```
$("<option/>").val(m.id).text(m.title).appendTo("#movies");
```

To

```
$("#movies").append('<option val='+m.id+'>'+m.title+'</option>')
```

Above line of code will work as you want